# Angular - error TS2554: Expected 0 arguments, but got 3

Tags: angular, typescript

I am running into the following ERROR:

```
src/app/data.service.ts(11,7): error TS2554: Expected 0 arguments, but got 3.
src/app/data.service.ts(12,7): error TS2554: Expected 0 arguments, but got 3.
```

I am new to Angular and my code appears to be the same as the tutorial I am following.

My code can be seen below

**data.service.ts:**

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

    @Injectable()
    export class DataService {

    constructor() { }

      getList(callback) {
        //TODO: Change it with a real Web Service    
        const list = [
          new Coffee("Double Espresso", "Sunny Cafe", new PlaceLocation("123 Market St", "San Francisco")),
          new Coffee("Caramel Americano", "Starcoffee", new PlaceLocation("Gran Via 34", "Madrid"))
        ];
        callback(list);
      }

      save(coffee, callback) {
        //TODO: Change it with a real Web Service
        callback(true);
      }

    }
```

**data.service.spec.ts:**

```
    import { TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';

    import { DataService } from './data.service';

    describe('DataService', () => {
      beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          providers: [DataService]
        });
      });

      it('should be created', inject([DataService], (service: DataService) => {
        expect(service).toBeTruthy();
      }));
    });
```

### Update

As requested in comments below.

**Coffee.ts:**

```
    class Coffee {

        // Properties
        type: string;
        rating: number;
        notes: string;
        tastingRating: TastingRating;

        constructor(public name: string, public place: string, public location: PlaceLocation) {

        }
    }
```

In case **PlaceLocation.ts** is needed:

```
    class PlaceLocation {

        constructor(public address: string = "", 
                    public city: string = "",
                    public latitude: number = null,
                    public longitude: number = null) {

                    }
    }
```

Comment: The error thrown from app.service.ts file. You need to share app.service.ts file

Comment: Share us your `Coffee` class, you are passing 3 args to the constructor, but your `Coffee` probably don't have a constructor to accept 3 args.

Comment: Just added the 2 classes (coffee and placelocation) thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Are you using angular cli? If so you probably need to re-run `ng serve`

Comment: using angular cli, when I run build or serve that is when I am getting the error. I've also tried to clean and that doesnt appear to help either

Comment: Do you declare Coffee class twice?

Comment: Not that I can tell, but you are right it is something to do with my classes, whether it be coffee or placelocation not sure yet.  removing the new Coffee lines from the code have stopped the error.  Thank you guys for helping point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before you create new object from existing class I think you want to import it in the component.

```
import {Coffee} from '<relative path>'
```

try importing Coffee from correct path.